I want to export a PowerPoint presentation using HTML2Canvas in Angular
I want to export a PowerPoint presentation using HTML2Canvas. The export works when I have only one gridster-item, but it doesn't work when I have two or more. Can you help me fix this issue?
Even when it captures two or more gridster-items, it only captures half of the div. This is the issue I'm facing.
<div>
    <gridster *ngIf="widgets?.length" [options]="options"
        <gridster-item *ngFor="let widget of widgets" [item]="widget">
            <ng-container [app-widget]="{ item: widget }"></ng-container>
        </gridster-item>
    </gridster>
</div>

<button mat-raised-button (click)="pptExport()">Export PPT</button>

// Export Function where my components there
async pptExport(): Promise<void> {
    const gridster = document.querySelector('gridster');

    if (!gridster) {
      console.log('Gridster element not found.');
      return;
    }

    const gridsterItems = gridster.querySelectorAll('gridster-item');

    if (gridsterItems.length === 0) {
      console.log('No gridster items found.');
      return;
    }

    const itemsArray = Array.from(gridsterItems);
    itemsArray.pop();

    try {
      await this.exportPPT.exportToPpt(itemsArray as HTMLElement[], this.pagename);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error exporting to PowerPoint:', error);
    }
 }


// Services
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
import pptxgen from 'pptxgenjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ExportPPTService {

    constructor() { }

    private captureElement(element: HTMLElement): Promise<HTMLCanvasElement> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center' });
            setTimeout(() => {
                html2canvas(element, { scrollY: -window.scrollY }).then((canvas) => {
                    resolve(canvas);
                }).catch((error) => {
                    reject(error);
                });
            }, 2000); // Increased timeout to ensure element is rendered
        });
    }

    private sleep(ms: number): Promise<void> {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }

    private async captureAllElements(elements: HTMLElement[]): Promise<{ canvas: HTMLCanvasElement, rect: DOMRect }[]> {
        const results: { canvas: HTMLCanvasElement, rect: DOMRect }[] = [];
        for (const element of elements) {
            try {
                const canvas = await this.captureElement(element);
                const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
                results.push({ canvas, rect });
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error capturing element:', error);
            }
            await this.sleep(2000); // Wait for 2 seconds between captures
        }
        return results;
    }

    async exportToPpt(containers: HTMLElement[], headerName: string): Promise<void> {
        const pptx = new pptxgen();
        pptx.layout = 'LAYOUT_WIDE';

        pptx.defineSlideMaster({
            title: 'MASTER_SLIDE',
            background: { color: 'FFFFFF' },
            objects: [
                {
                    image: {
                        x: 11.3,
                        y: 6.4,
                        w: 1.67,
                        h: 0.65,
                        path: 'assets/SCRAII_Logo.png',
                    },
                },
            ],
            slideNumber: { x: 0.3, y: '90%' },
        });

        const results = await this.captureAllElements(containers);

        let slide = pptx.addSlide({ masterName: 'MASTER_SLIDE' });
        const margin = 0.2;
        const slideWidth = 13.33 - (2 * margin);

        const addHeader = (slide: pptxgen.Slide) => {
            slide.addText(
                [{ text: headerName, options: { color: '#212529', fontSize: 14, fontFace: 'Poppins Black' } }],
                { x: margin, y: margin }
            );
        };

        addHeader(slide);

        results.forEach(({ canvas, rect }, index) => {
            const itemWidth = rect.width / 96;
            const itemHeight = rect.height / 96;

            const xPosition = rect.left / 96;
            const yPosition = rect.top / 96;

            let adjustedWidth = itemWidth;
            let adjustedHeight = itemHeight;

            if (itemWidth > slideWidth) {
                const scaleFactor = slideWidth / itemWidth;
                adjustedWidth = slideWidth;
                adjustedHeight = itemHeight * scaleFactor;
            }

            slide.addImage({
                data: canvas.toDataURL(),
                x: xPosition + margin,
                y: yPosition + margin,
                w: adjustedWidth,
                h: adjustedHeight
            });
        });

        pptx.writeFile({ fileName: headerName + '.pptx' });
    }
}

